# How to edit (or request an edit to) a typo in a bounty message?

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, bounties, bounty-remarks

I just started a bounty for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485687/extracting-pairs-of-words-using-string-split) but made a typo ("seem" instead if "seen").

How can I edit it?

If I can't, would it be an acceptable use of a flag to ask for it to be corrected?

Comment: Moderators can't edit it either...

Comment: @animuson well that's a bit crap that obvious errors can't be corrected. People spend rep - it seems reasonable to have the msg editable, even if via a flag

Comment: @animuson In this case though (since it's only a fairly new bounty) - isn't it technically possible to utilise discretion and refund the bounty, allowing Bohemian to issue it again, but being a bit more careful with their typing? :P

Comment: @JonClements Technically possible, but it might also require him to double the bounty amount. I'm not sure if bounties manually removed by moderators affect the minimum bounty amount in the future, but my gut doubts that there is a special check to prevent those from counting.

Comment: @animuson I think he has enough rep. to spare an additional 50 if he's that concerned about the typo :P

Comment: This question is more about capability and functionality of the site. The actual typo I can live with. And I don't want a "refund". It just seem to be a (small) feature gap.